# Prevent a Staging task from being created when you Undo Checkout

Tags: kentico

In Kentico 8.2, when I "Undo Checkout" a Staging task is created. So, I have to remember to always delete the task after undoing checkout. Is there a setting or some other way to prevent the creation of new Staging tasks when a checkout is undone?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure there are new staging tasks created when Undo check-out? Do you have any customizations or workflows with custom steps? What kind of workflow do you use?

It is possible to access [global events](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Reference+-+Global+system+events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-WorkflowEvents) and customize behavior something like (in your Old_App_Code):

```cs
using CMS.Base;
using CMS.Synchronization;

[CustomVersioningTasksHandler]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
private class CustomVersioningTasksHandler : CMSLoaderAttribute
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        StagingEvents.LogTask.Before += LogTask_Before;
    }
    void LogTask_Before(object sender, StagingLogTaskEventArgs e)
    {
        //if sender or e contains info that origin is undo checkout
        //{
        //    e.Cancel();
        //}
    }
}
}
```

Please double check which action creates your staging tasks. If you do not want to log tasks eg. for every document update, you can "disable it" like:

```
if (e.Task.TaskType == CMS.DataEngine.TaskTypeEnum.UpdateDocument)
{
    e.Cancel();
}
```

Feel free to check all *TaskTypeEnum* options and choose the one which fits your needs best.

Comment: I'll take a look at this approach. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, if I'm not mistaken, a new version is created while performing check-out (not undoing it)... this has to be reflected in the condition. Otherwise, this approach is correct.

Comment: You are right - I`ve just tried it and new tasks are created while performing check-out BUT only if you are using versioning without workflow. I am not able to find another scenario when are tasks created while check-out or undo checkout.

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting to stop this.  There is also no reason to not let this sync over to your other environment.

Comment: Right, but if there are other staged tasks that aren't going to be moved to the next environment, it creates a situation where you have to select only certain tasks to move, and it is easy for these ones that don't cause any harm (but aren't necessary) to be forgotten (especially when there are multiple developers undoing checkouts). It can lead to clutter. If all tasks are getting moved, then a select all is easy enough. Thanks for you input.

Comment: Those specifics would have been good to know in your original post. :)